# Selecting rows with highest date

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following query that throws a result like in the example:

```
SELECT            P.IdArt, P.IdAdr, P.gDate, P.Price
FROM              dbo.T_PriceData AS P INNER JOIN
                  dbo.T_Adr AS A ON P.IdAdr = A.IdAdr INNER JOIN
                  dbo.T_Stat AS S ON A.IdStat = S.IdStat
GROUP BY          P.IdArt, P.IdAdr, P.gDate, P.Price

  IdArt  IdAdr     gDate      Price
    1     10    01/01/2018     1.25
    1     10    02/01/2018     1.17     
    1     10    03/01/2018     1.18
    2     15    01/01/2018     1.03
    2     18    10/01/2018     0.12
    3     25    12/01/2018     0.98
    3     25    28/01/2018     1.99
    4     30    15/01/2018     2.55
    5     35    08/01/2018     0.11
```

The final result I want is:

> - When the IdArt and IdAdr are the same, there should be only one row with the highest date of all rows (CASE IdArt 1)
> - When IdArt is the same but IdAdr is different, there should be a row with each IdAdr with the highest date for each IdAdr. (CASE IdArt 2)
> - Price doens't affect anything.

So the final table I would like to have is:

```
IdArt  IdAdr     gDate      Price
1      10      03/01/2018    1.18
2      15      01/01/2018    1.03
2      18      10/01/2018    0.12
3      25      28/01/2018    1.99
4      30      15/01/2018    2.55
5      35      08/01/2018    0.11
```

How can I do that?
I tried with a having clausule selecting by MAX(gDate) but, of course, I only get one row with the max date from the whole database.

Comment: Isn't your first requirement already provided by your second? Isn't this just "every unique combination of idArt and idAdr should produce one output row"?

Comment: Hint: `MAX(gDate), MAX(Price) ... GROUP BY IdArt, IdAdr`

Comment: @Sami this is a popular question of getting rows with max in one column. Generally, it go to a `() IN ()`; `INNER JOIN max_table`; .... `MAX(price)` should not work.

Comment: @Sami using `MAX` would return the wrong values; such as the price `1.25` for the date `03/01/2018` on `ID` `1`.

Answer (score 2):

There are lots of answers out there on how to do this, however, this gets you what you are after:

```
SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES
       P.IdArt,
       P.IdAdr,
       P.gDate,
       P.Price
FROM dbo.T_PriceData P
     --INNER JOIN dbo.T_Adr A ON P.IdAdr = A.IdAdr --You don't reference this in the SELECT or WHERE. Why is it here?
     --INNER JOIN dbo.T_Stat S ON A.IdStat = S.IdStat --You don't reference this in the SELECT or WHERE. Why is it here?
ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY P.IdArt, P.IdAdr ORDER BY P.gDate DESC);
```

Edit: If the `JOIN`s are there to ensure that there are rows in the other tables, then as per the comments I would use `EXISTS`. If you just use `JOIN`, and only returning rows from the first table, then you could end up with duplicate rows.

```
SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES
       P.IdArt,
       P.IdAdr,
       P.gDate,
       P.Price
FROM dbo.T_PriceData P
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM dbo.T_Adr A
              WHERE P.IdAdr = A.IdAdr)
  AND EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM dbo.T_Stat S
              WHERE A.IdStat = S.IdStat)
ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY P.IdArt, P.IdAdr ORDER BY P.gDate DESC);
```

Comment: The `INNER JOIN` is condition that that row has reference in those other two tables. You can only omit it if it's a `LEFT JOIN`. Or maybe I'm wrong, and the query itself didn't has that intention...

Comment: I would personally go with an `EXISTS` then @PhamX.Bach. Otherwise, if these are many-to-one relationships you could end up with multiple duplicate rows.

Comment: No, that might nothelp here @RadimBača, as then you would have multiple rows for the same date. The OP only wants one.

Comment: The first one seems to work fine. Just so I understand... what does the "WITH TIES" clausule there?

Comment: It does what it implies in truth. In the event of a Tie, all the tieing rows are returned. In this case, where the value from `ROW_NUMBER` is 1, @Nanaki.

Answer (score 1):

You want the highest date for each `IdArt`/`IdAdr` combination.  Window functions are tempting, but the most efficient method is often a correlated subquery.

Your query is only selecting from `T_PriceData`, so the rest of the query (the joins and `group by`) do not seem necessary -- unless the joins are filtering the data which seems unlikely because the joins are to reference tables.

So I would recommend:

```
SELECT P.IdArt, P.IdAdr, P.gDate, P.Price
FROM dbo.T_PriceData P 
WHERE P.gDate = (SELECT MAX(P2.gDate)
                 FROM dbo.T_PriceData P2
                 WHERE P2.IdArt = P.IdArt AND
                       P2.IAdr = P.IdAdr
                );
```

For performance you want indexes on `(IdArt, IdAdr, gDate)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ROW_Number()`:

```
SELECT 
q.IdArt 
, q.IdArt
, q.IdADr   
, q.gDate
, q.Price
FROM (
SELECT 
  t.IdArt
, t.IdADr   
, t.gDate
, t.Price
, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t.IdArt, t.IdADr ORDER BY t.gDate DESC) rn
FROM dbo.T_PriceData t
) q
WHERE q.rn = 1
```